# How to define an extern const in constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constants

Two config.json files hold values that I want to store into constants. My plan was to load and parse the json file in the constructor of the corresponding classes and assign the values to constants. However, in debugging mode, the error " ... LNK2019: unresolved external symbol..." occurs.

So, is it not possible to define constants in a constructor?

Since the values of the constants depend on the variable `VARIANT`, I've made a  `ifelse` to read the correct .json file.

```
// constants.h
extern const int    BARL;
extern const int BAR_TOL;

// constants.cpp
Constants::Constants() {
    Json::Reader reader;
    Json::Value root;

    #if VARIANT == A
        std::ifstream config_a_file("a.json");
        reader.parse(config_a_file, root);
    #elif VARIANT == B
        std::ifstream config_b_file("b.json");
        reader.parse(config_b_file, root);
    #endif

    const int   BARL = root["BARL"].asInt();
    const int   BAR_TOL = BARL * 3;
}
```

What I expect is that the constants `BARL` and `BAR_TOL` can be used in the entire constants.cpp class. However, their definition cannot be found.

Comment: These constants must be defined at the translation unit scope. What you are trying to do won't work.

Comment: The constructor you show define two new and totally distinct variables `BARL` and `BAR_TOL`, unrelated to the ones you declared in the header file. Do you want these variables to be in the global scope? In a namespace? Or as members of a class?

Comment: But they are not constants if you change their values at runtime. Try dropping the *const* qualifier on them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When declaring external variables, the scope they appear in must match the scope they are defined in, to the namespace level. And you can't define two globals with external linkage in block scope at all.

Putting aside the discussion<sup>1</sup> about why you should be careful with such global constants, I'd say you are going about this wrong. Since you have a `Constants` class, just expose those constants as members, and declare a single external `Constants` instance. Something like:

```
struct Constants {
    int    BARL;
    int BAR_TOL;
    Constants();
};

extern Constants const constants;
```

Then other code may deal with the better namespaced `constants.BARL`, which is itself a constant since it's a sub-object of the const `constants` object.

The corresponding cpp file then becomes this:

```
Constants const constants; // definition

Constants::Constants() {
    Json::Reader reader;
    Json::Value root;

    #if VARIANT == A
        std::ifstream config_a_file("a.json");
        reader.parse(config_a_file, root);
    #elif VARIANT == B
        std::ifstream config_b_file("b.json");
        reader.parse(config_b_file, root);
    #endif

    BARL = root["BARL"].asInt(); // assignment
    BAR_TOL = BARL * 3;
}
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - For that, you can browse [static-order-fiasco](/questions/tagged/static-order-fiasco) for many examples about why the unspecified initialization order between static variables in different translation units can cause headaches.</sub>